# Is it possible to disprove continuity using $\epsilon -\delta$ approach?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

I am trying to prove that the function $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
5 x-2 & \text { if } x \neq 1 \\
-2 & \text { if } x=1
\end{array}\right.$$ is Discontinuous at $x=1$ using $\epsilon -\delta$ method.

Since $f(1)=-2$ ,we need to show that, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $x \in (1-\delta,1)\cup(1,1+\delta)$ $\implies$ $|f(x)+2|>\epsilon$

But not able to proceed?

Comment: $\epsilon - \delta$ proof will show you that the limit is equal to -3.   Then discontinuity occurs because the function value is not -3 at 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show continuity, you have to find a $\delta$ for any $\epsilon$.

To show discontinuity, you have to find an $\epsilon$ for which there is no $\delta$.

The gap between $\lim_{x \to 1} 5x-2 = 3$ and $f(1) = -2$ is $5$.  So for any $\epsilon < 5$ it should be impossible to find a $\delta$ to satisfy the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to show is that, for some $\varepsilon>0$, for every $\delta>0$ there is some number $x$ such that $|x-1|<\delta$ and that $|f(x)-f(1)|\geqslant\varepsilon$.

Take $\varepsilon=4$. Now, for any $\delta>0$, take any $x$ such that $0<|x-1|<\delta$ and also that $|x-1|<\frac15$. Now, note that\begin{align}|x-1|<\frac15&\iff\frac45<x<\frac65\\&\iff2<5x-2<4\\&\iff2<f(x)<4\\&\iff4<f(x)-f(1)<6.\end{align}So, $|f(x)-f(1)|\geqslant1=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Does it mean you are choosing $\delta=\frac{1}{5}$ and why you are selecting that particularly? Why not $|x-1|<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I **cannot** choose $\delta$ (and neither can you). The number $\delta$ can be **any** number greater than $0$. I chose $\frac15$ because I made the computations and it turned out that it worked.

Comment: But if do $|x-1|<\frac{1}{2}$, we end up in $2.5 <f(x)-f(2) <7.5$, but $\epsilon =4$ lies here right? So do you mean to say, if we find one counter example(yours), we can conclude that $f$ is discontinuous?

Comment: Did you mean $f(x)-f(\color{red}1)$ here?

Comment: Anyway, I don't see the point of answering your questions. In your question, you asked for a $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof, and then you have accepted a proof which is *not* of that kind, since it uses the fact that $\lim_{x\to1}5x-2=3$.

Comment: Ya i upvoted(not accepted) because i felt this approach is different.